# Add primary key to PostgreSQL table only if it does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, alter-table, postgresql-9.1

I have simple table creating script in Postgres 9.1. I need it to create the table with 
2-attributes PK only if it does not exist.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "mail_app_recipients"
(
    "id_draft" Integer NOT NULL,
    "id_person" Integer NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE); -- this is OK

ALTER TABLE "mail_app_recipients" ADD PRIMARY KEY IF NOT EXISTS ("id_draft","id_person");
-- this is problem since "IF NOT EXISTS" is not allowed.
```

Any solution how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not include the PK definition inside the CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mail_app_recipients
(
    id_draft Integer NOT NULL,
    id_person Integer NOT NULL,
    constraint pk_mail_app_recipients primary key (id_draft, id_person)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Separate ADD PRIMARY KEY IF NOT EXISTS is impossible?

Comment: No, there is no `IF NOT EXISTS` option for the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: cool stuff, helped me to this elegantly and idempotent with Ansible!

Answer (score 52):

You could do something like the following, however it is better to include it in the create table as a_horse_with_no_name suggests.

```
if NOT exists (select constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints where table_name = 'table_name' and constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY') then

ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

end if;
```

Comment: It's important to notice that this code should be executed within `DO $$ BEGIN ... END $$;`,  [see](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

Answer (score 26):

You can try to `DROP` it before creating it (`DROP` has the `IF EXISTS` clause):

```
ALTER TABLE mail_app_recipients DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS mail_app_recipients_pkey;
ALTER TABLE mail_app_recipients ADD CONSTRAINT mail_app_recipients_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("id_draft","id_person");
```

Note that this require that you give a name to the primary key constraint - in this example `mail_app_recipients_pkey`.